# Calendar in php throwing page not found when changing years

Tags: php, calendar

I have some php code which displays the current month in calendar format and has some navigation links at the top of the calendar which allow navigation per month (next and previous).

The code is below - I borrowed this from another source (it's not my code) and my mind has failed me as to where, apologies or I would cite the source.  It's been useful for me.

The error I'm finding is that when attempting to navigate to a year outside of the current year (both forward and backwards) - my site (which is a wordpress site) throws a page not found error.  I'm a bit confused, may I ask for assistance from the wise community herein please?

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['month'])) $_REQUEST['month'] = date('n');
if (!isset($_REQUEST['year'])) $_REQUEST['year'] = date('Y');
$cMonth = $_REQUEST['month'];
$cYear = $_REQUEST['year'];

... more code in between...

$month = strftime('%m', time());
$cur_year = strftime('%Y', time());
$monthNames = Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;

if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}

...more code here not really relevant...

echo "<div class='box-a-program'><table class='calendar-direction'><tr>
<td width='33%'><a href='/client-meal-calendar/?month=".$prev_month."&year=".$prev_year."'>Previous</a></td>
<td width='33%'><a href='/client-meal-calendar/?month=".$month."&year=".$cur_year."'>Today</a></td>
<td width='33%'><a href='/client-meal-calendar/?month=".$next_month."&year=".$next_year."'>Next</a></td>
</tr></table>

<table class='calendar'><tr><th colspan='7'><strong>".$monthNames[$cMonth-1]." ".$cYear."</strong></th></tr>

<tr>
<th><strong>S</strong></th>
<th><strong>M</strong></th>
<th><strong>T</strong></th>
<th><strong>W</strong></th>
<th><strong>T</strong></th>
<th><strong>F</strong></th>
<th><strong>S</strong></th>
</tr><tbody>";

$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date('t',$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
$today_number = strftime("%e",time());
$today_number = (int)$today_number;

for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {

    if ((($i - $startday + 1) == $today_number) && ($cMonth == $month)) {
        $wrap = "today";
    } else {
        $wrap = "nottoday"; }

    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";

    if($i < $startday) {
        echo "<td></td>";
    } else {

...some more code that does things in here...

        echo "<td height='20px' class=".$wrap.">".($i - $startday + 1). ...some code in here for some form work ... </td>"; 
    }

    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table></div>";
```

EDIT: Sorry, I should clarify.  What I'm asking is can anyone see errors in the code which would cause a problem when moving from December of the current year forward to January of the next year, or from January of the current year back to December of the previous year?

Comment: What does the URL look like for a page that works, and for one that doesn't?

Comment: P.S. Since you're using double quotes, you can replace `".$prev_month."` and the like with `{$prev_month}`. In most cases even just `$prev_month` would be fine all by itself. For example, `'/client-meal-calendar/?month=$prev_month&year=$prev_year'` should work fine there. Look up PHP variable interpolation for more details.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Greg.  Q1: the URL that works is "https://...domain and page.../?month=12&year=2018" and one that fails is "https://...domain and page.../?month=1&year=2019".  You can substitute any number into month, if the year is 2018 it works well, if the year is any other year it fails to my complete mystification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a silly-billy.  This was an almost exact same problem posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272766/wordpress-customized-calendar-next-and-previous-year-gives-404?rq=1)

The answer is to change the variables used in $_GET and subsequently within the code.  month and year are reserved names.

...trick for the un-initiated.